# How can I rsync password protected shared folder over windows smb?

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, file-sharing, samba, rsync

I'm using computers with Windows xp operating system.

What had been done:

- Shared folder **C:\123** was created on host **192.168.0.2**
- User with name **User** and password **123** was created on the same host
- **User** was granted with full access to the folder **C:\123**

Now I'm trying to sync this folder using **rsync** with credetials username: **User** and password: **123**:

```
rsync.exe -rav --delete --rsh=smb //User:123@/192.168.0.2/123/  ../tmp
sending incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "//User:123@/192.168.0.2/123" failed: No such file or directo
ry (2)

sent 18 bytes  received 12 bytes  6.67 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
```

What should I try next? How can I rsync password protected shared folder over windows smb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsync` doesn't work over file sharing protocols; it must open a **shell** on the remote system so that it can run `rsync` there and communicate with it. If you need to use a file sharing protocol instead then you must mount the share locally and have `rsync` treat it as a local transfer instead.